# Controlling a 3G modem using AT commands

Tags: at-command, 3g, modem

Just wondering if anyone has experience with controlling a 3G card network connection using AT commands.

We have a embedded device that periodically drops off the 3G network and fails to re-establish a connection.  So I was wondering if it is possible to control the card using the AT command set and force it to reconnect when network errors are detected.

If so what are the commands one would use.  We have Sierra Wireless MC8705 cards.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to use AT+CFUN (check your modems docs for the write parameter for this command) to do a power cycle and let it automatically reconnect. There are AT Command guides for Sierra Wireless modems which you can directly get from their website.